# Deleting records from fact table and dimension table

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to delete records from target table as records deleted from a source. I used merge/rows and delete stop both individuals, but I solved my problem in `delete case` when I deleted record from source. Then, after transformation fact table had only that record which was deleted from the source while it must had all those instead of this. I want the same method for the `dim table` also.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssb8N.png)

Comment: Is it possible to have a 4 line example of what you try to achieve?

Comment: I have rental(source) table and want to sync with my warehouse fact_rental as any records deleted from a source that would be deleted in the warehouse too.Want to do on dim and fact table.
I tried to delete step but not successful